# Wordpress change image link to attachment page on old posts - bulk change

Tags: php, image, wordpress, bulk

Is there a way to change all old posts images links?

I have this blog, that have more than 2.000 posts and each post with at least 10 images. All the images are linked to file. Now I created an attachment page template for the images. The new posts are working well with default images linking to the attachment page.

But I would like to know if is it possible to bulk replace all image links from older posts (that are linking to file) to the attachment page without opening each post and edit each image.

I searched on the web and couldn't find anything about replace the image link on old posts, I found only things about change the default image links on new posts created, which is working fine already on my blog.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: do you feel confortable with MYSQL? if you do, the REPLACE function could help you with this.

Comment: not very confortable with MYSQL. But I search for how to do it, and coldn't find. I tried this code from other post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33724/remove-links-from-images-using-functions-php . It works removing the links. But I'm searching something to change the links from file to attachment page... Still can't find any solution. Thanks